# Bounty expired before I could assign it to answer: punish me, not my answerer!

Tags: feature-request, bounties, expired-bounty

I [asked a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233681/sign-error-proving-product-rule-for-the-laplacian-on-a-product-of-riemannian-man/) which didn't get an answer, so I assigned it a bounty. There was still no activity on my question for most of the bounty period, but then near the end of the period, a correct answer came in. It was a weekend and I was travelling for the holiday and didn't check regularly that day, so I missed the closing of the bounty period and the grace period. I was delighted to see the answer on Monday, but of course then it was too late to award the bounty, and the answer had no upvotes.

It's my fault for not checking regularly enough. Punish me, but don't punish my answerer! I think it should be possible to assign a bounty to questions that came in during the bounty period, even after the window has closed. It seems to me like the policies are not flexible enough in this area.

Is there any way an admin can override the software and policy and do this on my behalf?

Comment: Well, you _are_ "punished" and the answerer isn't any worse off. The reputation you put up for the bounty is gone, and you could put up another one if you feel really strongly that the answer deserves a rep bonus.

Comment: Isn't there a (somewhat long) grace period after the bounty ends?  Where were you then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Comment: I felt sorry for you, and the guy who had answered :)

Comment: Sure, show-off. Now let me flag this as "not an answer". ;) Thanks

Comment: @Bart Go ahead, I dare you! I have 10k powaz, I SEE ALL! Well, OK, most. And all I can do is counterflag as invalid. But...you get the point :P

Comment: Let the battle COMMENCE!!!!

Comment: Thank you, @Manishearth. I do think the policy could be more flexible here, but I'm happy that Mario will get the reputation he was promised.

Comment: @ziggurism: Well, there already is a grace period, I don't see what more can be done. (Also, thanks for reminding me, forgot to bounty.. Though I would have gotten the email reminder sometime soon anyway)

Answer (score 7):

I would regard this as a case of "sh*t happens". Normally it is up to you as the awarder of the bounty to make sure you can actually award it before it expires and the grace period (another bit of time awarded to you) is over. That is your responsibility.

And even if you forget to do so, half the bounty will automatically be awarded to a new answer which gathers enough upvotes before the bounty expires. So that already at least partially addresses an OP who is not paying attention. (For whatever legitimate reason). Unfortunately however, the answer did not qualify for that, so the author was out of luck there.

Still, what I would not like to see happen however is an indefinite ability to award a bounty. Why not? I don't want users to dangle bounties in front of other user's faces as carrots. "Sure I'll award you the bounty if you can improve your answer just this last little bit".

Yours is an unfortunate case and I'm sure you are by no means an abusive user of the system. But even the author of the answer doesn't hold it against you. If you really feel strongly about it, you can award a new bounty to the specific answer, though that would have to be substantially higher. It's up to you to decide if you think that's worth it.

Comment: Can I award a small new bounty? When I go to "add bounty", the minimum I can award now is 300, when the original bounty was only 250. Why is this number going up?

Comment: Ah damn, yeah, you are of course right. Any additional bounty you offer has to be at least twice the initial bounty. I'll correct that.

Comment: @ziggurism Of note, your original bounty [was 150](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/233681/revisions), not 250, which explains why you can now only award a bounty of 300. And it seems one of our lovely users has started a new bounty to award the answer. What a feelgood ending that would be...sniff.